# How to use a custom BarcodeScanner plugin with phonegap build?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a simple phonegap project set up and configured in phonegap build. This works with the barcodescanner plugin.

I want to use a slightly modified version of the barcodeScanner plugin and have edited the CDVBarcodeScanner.mm file for that.

Now I want to use that version of the plugin. As far as I can see, that's not possible when using phonegap build?

When building locally with "cordova run ios" I get the error

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
```

I guess I don't have the proper provisioning profiles set up locally or something, however I configured them in phonegap build and they work fine.

Should I also configure them in my phonegap project locally? As far as the docs go, I could find a CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer in build.xconfig that I should leave alone?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the main question no, you can't use your custom BarcodeScanner plugin with phonegap build, you can submit your own plugins, but I don't think they will approve a barcode plugin if there is one available.

About the code signing problem, you have to install the provisioning profile you uploaded to phonegap build in your local machine, just double click it